# Javascript RegExp.test not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a strong password.

```
/*  Regular expression explained
o Must contain at least one number: (?=.*\d)
o Must contain at least one letter: (?=.*[a-zA-Z])
o Must contain at least one symbol: (?=.*[!@#$*_=|?{}\[\]~\-,.])
o No whitespace:                        (?=\S+$)
o Length 8 - 25 characters long:        .{8,25}
*/

pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
var PwdRegExpStr = "^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$*_=|?{}\[\]~\-,.])(?=\S+$).{8,25}$"
var PwdRegExp = new RegExp(PwdRegExpStr);
var PwdRegExpStr2 = "^.*(?=.{8,25})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$?]).*$"
var PwdRegExp2 = new RegExp(PwdRegExpStr2);

var patt =  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$*_=|?{}\[\]~\-,.])(?=\S+$).{8,25}$/
var patt2 = /^.*(?=.{8,25})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$/
alert("Pass:"+pass+" = "+PwdRegExp.test(pass)+" = "+PwdRegExp2.test(pass)+" = "+patt.test(pass)+" = "+patt2.test(pass));
```

I'm seeing the following results when i enter "qwer1234$":
Pass:qwer1234$ = false = false = true = true

Can you help me understand why they're not all evaluating true?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's trying to suggest that don't _validate_ passwords using regex?

Comment: That's weird, I'm kind of stumped.  Either way, [you should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) create expressions literally (`/^abc$/.test('abc')`) in JavaScript if you can.  And that's the one that returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'm actually passing into the javascript the minimum password length from configuration. That's why I was hoping to use the RegExp version to concatenate it into the string prior to defining the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is bad escaping.  When you specify the regex in the form of a string literal, you have to escape the backslashes.  So this:

```
"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$*_=|?{}\[\]~\-,.])(?=\S+$).{8,25}$"
```

...should be:

```
"^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$*_=|?{}\\[\\]~\\-,.])(?=\\S+$).{8,25}$"
```

---

On a side note, I don't see any need to write `(?=\S+$).{8,25}$` when `\S{8,25}$` will do.  And in your other version, the extra `.*` after the `^` makes no sense.  It still works, but you're making the regex engine do a lot more work than it should.